# Degree of extension of a prime field $\mathbb Q$ to an algebraically closed field $\mathbb F$

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

Given an algebraically closed field $\mathbb F$ and its prime field $\mathbb Q$, what would be the degree of extension $[\mathbb F:\mathbb Q]$? Is it always infinite? It for sure is for $[\mathbb C:\mathbb Q]$ since the latter is countable and the former is uncountable.

Comment: Yes, always infinite, as there are irreducible polynomials of arbitrarily high degree.

Comment: @JohnBrevik Much appreciated. I am not familiar with this part of algebra, can you enlighten me with a suitable reference? (not too Serge Lang please)

Comment: @JohnBrevik Never mind I figured out...so this arbitrarily high degree can just simply be $x^n=2$?

Comment: Yes, for example! There's a nice tidy reason why all these polynomials are irreducible.

Comment: @JohnBrevik Which is what....?

Comment: Eisenstein's criterion!

Comment: @JohnBrevik I learned! thank you so much...I should have learned some field and galois theory, damn...difficult to work theoretical in engineering...